# Outlook - convert server-side rules to be client-only

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a bunch (almost 100!) of Outlook rules, all of which are server-side, and most of which move the email from Inbox into a different folder based on sender or words in the subject line.

This worked fine when I was only accessing Outlook from my work laptop. However, now I have to access email from my phone, and with the crappy phone interface, it's a pain to easily be able to see which subfolders actually contain emails and/or navigate to all the possible subfolders to check for unread emails being in there.

Is there any EASY way to convert these server-side rules into client-only rules 'en masse', so they will always run when I run Outlook on my laptop, but if I 'm out of the office for a few days and log in via my phone, they will still be in the Inbox and I can cherry-pick which ones are important?

I know I could go to each one and add a dummy behavior (play a sound) or something like that, so it is converted to a client-only rule, but does anyone have a better option so I don't have to do this for each rule individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook provides an option to bulk edit the rules. Go to Home tab > Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts, hold Ctrl (or Shift) key and click to select the rules you want to modify, the highlighted two options could help convert your server-side rules to client-side rules, as these two options are Outlook client-side operations. Moreover, these two actions won't make any big difference to your rules behavior.

[image]

[image]

[image]

BTW, when I tested with the 'Play a Sound' action, all rules were converted to client-sides rules (labelled with "(client-only)"). Since I don't want this change, I unselected the "Play a Sound" option, guess what, all rules were still marked with "(client-only)". You may test to see whether this is the same case in your Outlook. If it is the case, this should be the best option.

Comment: Excellent - that worked perfectly - I selected a sound and then unselected, and "Play a sound" was replaced by "On this computer only"... Thank you so much :)